# Promise Chaining/Race Conditions Server-side AngularJS DataTables

Tags: angularjs, datatables, promise, angular-datatables

We are using server side pagination on an AngularJS DataTable. This is the way that we are using form the page here that works great if just populating one table:
https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/340

Do you know of any way to ensure that these two objects won't conflict with one another in a race condition? It works fine if just populating one or the other, but the second we try to populate both, strangeness occurs.

The interesting thing is that it works fine for multiple datatables in IE, but doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome. Also it gets hungup on the second datatable rendering, and then completes sometimes after 5 minutes. That's why I'm thinking it's basically a race condition, because of the inconsistency.

Both are instant if only one or the other is selected.

HTML:

```
<table id="entity-grid" datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptionsSource1" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" class="table table-hover"></table>

<table id="entity-grid2" datatable="" dt-options="vm.dtOptionsSource2" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" class="table table-hover"></table>
```

JavaScript:

```
vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id', 'Id').notVisible(),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name', 'Name')
        ];

vm.dtOptionsSource1 = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withFnServerData(serverDataSource1)
            .withDataProp('data')
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('paging', true)
            .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
            .withPaginationType('numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withDOM('<"top">t<i"bottom"p><"clear">');

function serverDataSource1(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {

            //All the parameters you need is in the aoData variable
            var draw = aoData[0].value;
            var order = aoData[2].value;
            var start = aoData[3].value;
            var length = aoData[4].value;
            $scope.parameterSource1 = ourformDataSource1;

            //Then just call your service to get the records from server side
            $http.post('URL', $scope.parameterSource1).then(function(result){

                var records = {
                        'draw': draw,
                        'recordsTotal': result.total,
                        'recordsFiltered': result.filtered,
                        'data': result.records  
                    };
                fnCallback(records);
            });
        }

vm.dtOptionsSource2 = DTOptionsBuilder
            .newOptions()
            .withFnServerData(serverDataSource2)
            .withDataProp('data')
            .withOption('processing', true)
            .withOption('serverSide', true)
            .withOption('paging', true)
            .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
            .withPaginationType('numbers')
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withDOM('<"top">t<i"bottom"p><"clear">');

function serverDataSource2(sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {

            //All the parameters you need is in the aoData variable
            var draw = aoData[0].value;
            var order = aoData[2].value;
            var start = aoData[3].value;
            var length = aoData[4].value;
            $scope.parameterSource2 = ourformDataSource2;

            //Then just call your service to get the records from server side
            $http.post('URL', $scope.parameterSource2).then(function(result){

                var records = {
                        'draw': draw,
                        'recordsTotal': result.total,
                        'recordsFiltered': result.filtered,
                        'data': result.records  
                    };
                fnCallback(records);
            });
        }
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What's the actual problem, and what is the question?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem lies here and not for instance in the `filterService`. Both datatables controls seem pretty independent. They seem to share a `rowCallback` but if it is stateless, I don't see anything else that might cause interference.

Comment: Just edited the question to make it more clear. We have a $http.post happening in each function. The issue is that it only renders one datatable, not both. The second datatable just shows "Processing" and then eventually resolves 5 minutes later.